# Make a div sticky with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap v3 for a div that I would like to make 'sticky' once scrolled from its current position, either moved to the left or left in position.

```
<div id="trigger1">
    <table class="nav-justified">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Menu Area
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="text-right">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <a id="FilterDataLabel" class="btn btn-danger" data-target="#" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button">
                            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter">
                            </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Filter Filter Menu
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: look at this http://jsfiddle.net/oycv4hba/5/ .. and to get div current position use ..  $('div').offset().top;

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to use the CSS attribute `position: fixed;`

Look this example: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zanon/or86q4tp/).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a `div` to be placed somewhere in your page and when the page is scrolled the `div` will stick to the top. If this is right, then you can use this... `affix`.

[Here is a **Fiddle** with it doing this with a sticky `div`.](https://jsfiddle.net/775k3fm1/)

Try this and use in what you are coding here.

```
<script>
$('.stick-top').affix({
  offset: {top: 50}
});
</script>
```